# How can you do a safe, backwards-compatible "reverse-monkeypatch" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, reverse, monkeypatching

If your coworker "opens" ("monkeypatches") a class in Ruby and redefines some important functionality that you need to use, how do you access that original pre-monkeypatched functionality without breaking a system that already relies/has dependencies on his monkeypatched definitions?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context on what sort of monkeypatch this was?  (redefining a single method?  multiple?  something else?)

Comment: Let's say, for example, that he redefined the + method in Ruby's built-in Numeric class to do subtraction instead of addition and now I need to do addition in the app - how do I access the original functionality of the Numeric class's + method?

Comment: It might be worth asking if monkey patching is a good solution if you have are having this type of problem too - perhaps an explicit class or module would be a better approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the example of the method overriding, if you can get some code loaded before his monkey patch is loaded then you can alias the method.

```
class Fixnum
  alias_method :original_plus, :+
end

class Fixnum
  def +(x)
    self - x
  end
end

>> 5 + 3
=> 2
>> 5.original_plus(3)
=> 8
```

Comment: You could put your code in the same file directly before your coworker's monkeypatch, if you have access to the source code.  Otherwise the answer will depend on how your program is being loaded.

Comment: This is as close to a solution as I could imagine but I'm not sure how I could influence the order in which code is loaded. How could I insist on aliases being loaded before his monkey patches - simply by doing what you did here? Namely, inserting definitions at prior points in the source code - is that really all it takes?

Comment: Assuming you have access to his part of the codebase as well, just stick the alias in literally right above his monkeypatch.

Comment: Except for a REST scenario, wouldn't you always have access to the source in a Ruby cowork situation?

Answer (score 3):

I recently saw this in the rubyflow feed - its a simple library that lets you namespace top level constants called [aikidoka](http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/2009/05/10/aikidoka-prevents-ruby-namespace-collisions/).  Without any details of how/what is being monkey patched it is a bit tough to help.  In theory though you could use an approach like this to namespace the monkey-patched version of the class so that you can access both it and the original independently.

Comment: Doesn't this require you to refactor your codebase to use the new name - Twitter::Mash instead of Mash?

Comment: You will almost certainly have to refer to one of the versions by a different name even in the alias_method case answered above since you are defining the same functionality in 2 different ways

Answer (score 0):

Depends exactly what functionality was changed and in what way, but something implementing like Jim Wienrich's [BlankSlate](http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/BlankSlate.rdoc) class may help: